# How to do full text Search and Relevance matches in mysql and php?

Tags: php, mysql, search, pattern-matching, full-text-search

For Example. **Table1:**

**row1:**

> > 1. **Title:** php interview questions and answers
> > 2. **description:** PHP and mysql interview questions for all mnc companies
> > 3. **tags:** php,mysql

**row2**

> > 1. **Title:** bank aptitude interview questions and answers
> > 2. **description:** bank aptitude interview questions and general awareness questions
> > 3. **tags:** bank apptitude,bank

**query:** bank exam question and answers

**I used the Following code:**

```
$first_query = sql_query_first($search_term,$page); 

$list_info =sort_result(search($first_query,$search_term));

function search($querys,$term) {
shinee_library(); 
$co_se=0; $search_q=mysql_query($querys);

while (($list_info[$co_se] = mysql_fetch_assoc($search_q))) 
            {                           
            $name=0;$des=0;$re=0;$tag=0;
            $pattern =explode(" ",$term);$size_len=sizeof($pattern);                
            while($re< $size_len) {
                    if (preg_match("/".$pattern[$re]."/i", $list_info[$co_se]["name"])) {  $name=$name+1; }  
                    if (preg_match("/".$pattern[$re]."/i", $list_info[$co_se]["description"])) {  $des=$des+1; }                                                                        
                    $re++;
                }                               
            $arr1 = array_unique($pattern);
            $arr2 =  array_unique(explode(",",$list_info[$co_se]["tags"]));                     
            foreach($arr2 as $val)  {  if(in_array($val, $arr1)) { $tag=3; break;  }         }                                      
            $list_info[$co_se]["tit_rel"]=(($name/$size_len)+($des/$size_len)/4)+$tag;              
            $co_se++;                                               
            }
mysql_close();      
return $list_info;
}




function sql_query_first($pattern,$page) {
    $searchitems=explode(" ", $pattern); $clause ="OR"; $query = "select * from doc_basic WHERE ( ";
for($i=0;$i<count($searchitems);$i++)
    { $queryappend .= "(name LIKE '% ".$searchitems[$i]." %' OR description LIKE '% ".$searchitems[$i]." %')";
        if($i<count($searchitems)-1) $queryappend .= $clause;
    } 
    $query .=$queryappend.$attach.") LIMIT ".($page-1)."0 , ".$page."0";   


  return $query;
}

function sort_result($info) { 
        foreach ($info as $key => $row) { $tit_rel[$key]  = $row['tit_rel'];  }
        array_multisort($tit_rel, SORT_DESC,  $info);       
        return  $info;
    }
```

**Desired Output:**

```
result1
>1. Title: bank aptitude interview questions and answers
>2. description: bank aptitude interview questions and general awareness questions
>3. tags: bank apptitude,bank

result2:
>1. Title: php interview questions and answers
>2. description: PHP and mysql interview questions for all mnc companies
>3. tags: php,mysql
```

*fetch the result by  Relevance matches and sort the result by tag matches*

Comment: [`FULLTEXT search`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) ?

Comment: yes,,, full text relevance matches ... and sort result by tag...